# Reload Singleton Values Java

Tags: java, database, class, static, singleton

This is my first question in this page, I hope someone help me to understand this code related with a singleton class in Java.

There is a function called reloadValues() and connect to a database and assign the coresponding values to public static final variables in a singleton class.

The function is declared in this way:

```
public static void reLoadValues()
```

But I saw a piece of code at the end of the class:

```
 static { reloadValues(); }
```

And until now I am wondering in which moment is executed and which is the functionality.

Comment: Static blocks are executed when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When class is loaded, all static fields are initialized and static initializer block are executed. And class is loaded, when it is first required by JVM.

Comment: To emphasize: this happens before any objects of that class have been created